# Best (Free) Certificate management tools

Tags: pki

I recently downloaded a neat java tool for managing certificate files - like PEM, PFX, etc.. From memory it was written in Java but, for the life of me i can't find it (cleared download list and non-obvious file name!).

This led me to throw open the question - what free tools are there for managing certs? The aforementioned tool could generate certs as well as display them via it's UI.

I just want something to track my certs and generally make it easier to view their details without having to use formal CA tooling or keytool/other cmd line tools JUST to see which certs i'm dealing with.

Answer (score 4):

A colleague of mine has found a whole bunch - including the one that i'd used before (Portecle). Thanks Shayne!

http://yellowcat1.free.fr/keytool_iui.html

Or this:  http://www.gria.org/downloads/tpc/keytool-gui-zip/griafile_view  (apparently superseded by this commercial product:  http://www.lazgosoftware.com/kse/ )

Or http://portecle.sf.net

Answer (score 3):

The first one is OpenCA. [htp://www.openca.org/](http://www.openca.org/)

Answer (score 2):

I have successfully tried this solution:

http://gnomint.sourceforge.net/

gnoMint is an X.509 Certification Authority management tool.

Currently, it has two different interfaces: one for GTK/Gnome environments, and another one for command-line.

It's free software, under the GNU/GPL license.

Answer (score 1):

If you can stand not using a GUI, then [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org) is as good as it gets. There are binary packages for [windows platforms](http://www.openssl.org/related/binaries.html).